# Access the variable from one function to another function

Tags: php, oop, phpmailer

I know this might be something I am missing on my side.
I am working on PHP, since I am new to it, I am facing a problem with accessing the variables from one function to another in the same class.

I am having a page called function.php and declared the variable globally.

This is my code

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
include 'Config.php';

/**
 *
 *
 */
class function
{
    public $insert = array();

    public function store()
    {

        $db = new Config();

        $insert = array(
            'date' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['Date']) ,
            'Tov' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['Tov']) ,
            'Name' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['Name']) ,
            'rh_first' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['rh_first']) ,
            'se_second' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['se_second']) ,
            'pk_third' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['pk_third'])
        );
        return $insert;
    }

    public function Send()
    {
        //Load Composer's autoloader
        require 'vendor/autoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer(); // Passing `true` enables exceptions
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'yyyy'; // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to


        if ($this->insert['rh_first'] == "P") {
            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx');
            $mail->addAddress('xvb@gmail.com', 'xvb');
            //content
            $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Test';
            $mail->Body = 'Test email';
        }
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx');
        $mail->addAddress('yyyya@gmail.com', 'yyyya');

        // $mail->addCC('asdfg@gmail.com');
        //Attachments
        $mail->addAttachment('lobbyq.png', 'sample.png'); // Add attachments
        // Optional name
        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Test2';
        $mail->Body = 'Test2 messagwe';

        if (!$mail->send()) {;
            return "Message not sent" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            return "email send";
        }
    }
}
```

The above code contain a function to store and send email via phpmailer

There are six fields to store in database (on Function store()) where last three are radio buttons.

When I tried to run the code got an error as `Undefined index 'rh_first'` as I didn't initialize it in global.But i did as `$insert = array();` globally.

Please suggest me a better way to access the key of the array variable into another function of the same class.

Comment: Where do you call `store()` ?

Comment: On another page as final.php

Do you need the code of the page

Answer (score 2):

This function needs to *set* the value of `$this->insert`:

```
public function store()
{
    $db = new Config();

    $insert = array(
        'date' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['Date']) ,
        'Tov' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['Tov']) ,
        'Name' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['Name']) ,
        'rh_first' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['rh_first']) ,
        'se_second' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['se_second']) ,
        'pk_third' => mysqli_real_escape_string($db->connection, $_POST['pk_third'])
    );

    $this->insert = $insert;

    return $insert;
}
```

Notice the new line: `$this->insert = $insert;`?
This will set the property of your class to be the value of the `$insert` array.

Also, I left the fact that it returns the value of `$insert`, because I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, however, I think this function can just return void...

Comment: @NiyazAhamed What do you mean it works but shows the same error?

Comment: The "Undefined index 'rh_first' ". Anyway i have got the support from the community
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a global variable, but a class variable. And if you want to access it within the class, you have to use `$this->insert` instead of `$insert`, as the second one would be a function-scoped variable.

Anyways, try to rework your code. From my point of view, these inserted values could better live in a function argument.

Finally, you should place the autoloader on the outermost level, just after the `use` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the array using `$this->insert` since it is declared globally.

To get key and value use:

```
foreach ($this->insert as $key => value) {
    echo $value; // prints the values of insert
    echo $key;   // prints the keys of insert
}
```

Comment: I can but cannot able to access the key of the array using $this->insert['rh_first'].